# VS 11 Express beta Error Obtaining Developer Licence

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS 11 Express beta, when I tried to install the developer Licence for Windows 8
Consumer Preview, I get an error saying "We couldn't get
your developer Licence for Windows 8 Consumer Preview.
Please check your internet connection and try again."
However I am online. What can I do ?

Comment: @Will, I don't think this is too localized at all. It seems to be general problem hitting anyone who upgrades a Win7 dev box to Win8. Googlers are going to land on this question and the answer will be helpful.

Comment: @KateGregory: If the votes come to reopen, I won't stop it.  But this is only valid for a *specific type of install* for a CTP of a product that will be coming out later this year.  And this might even get fixed before that.  Googlers will still be able to find this question, and the answer pointing to the connect for the issue.  If Ishan wants me to reopen so he can accept, I'll do that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a problem when you upgrade windows 7 to windows 8. There is a bug open on connect that is being worked on.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727351/cant-agree-with-developer-license-in-visual-studio-11-beta